# Can't get tocloft's subanswer example to work

Tags: tocloft

The code is copy pasted from the [man on p. 15](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf). I'm using pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistentry[answer]{subanswer}{1}
\cftsetindents{subanswer}{1.5em}{3.0em} % ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.
\renewcommand{\thesubanswer}{\theanswer.\alph{subanswer}}
\newcommand{\subanswer}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subanswer}\par
  \textbf{\thesubanswer) #1}
  \addcontentsline{ans}{subanswer{\protect\numberline{\thesubanswer}#1}
  }
  \setcounter{ansdepth}{2}
  
\begin{document}

%\answer{Harder} The \ldots\subanswer{Reformulate the problem} It assists \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the source of the error. `\newlistentry` has the following input format:

```
\newlistentry[<within>]{<entry>}{<ext>}{<level-1>}
```

You (and the [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft)) didn't supply the `<ext>` argument. Then, that part of the documentation builds on some previous parts where it defines the `\answer` elements.

Here's a complete, minimal example that compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listanswername}{List of Answers}
\newlistof[section]{answer}{ans}{\listanswername}

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{answer}\par
  \noindent\textbf{Answer \theanswer. #1}
  \addcontentsline{ans}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theanswer}#1}\par}

\newlistentry[answer]{subanswer}{ans}{1}
\cftsetindents{subanswer}{1.5em}{3.0em}%
\renewcommand{\thesubanswer}{\theanswer.\alph{subanswer}}
\newcommand{\subanswer}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subanswer}\par
  \textbf{\thesubanswer) #1}
  \addcontentsline{ans}{subanswer}{\protect\numberline{\thesubanswer}#1}%
}
\setcounter{ansdepth}{2}
  
\begin{document}

\answer{Harder} The \ldots\subanswer{Reformulate the problem} It assists \ldots

\end{document}
```